# Which Purana has Shiva Ashtottara Stotram?

Tags: shiva, puranas, stotra

The [Shiva Ashtottara Stotram](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shiva108Str.html?lang=sa)  which starts as

> शिवोमहेश्वरश्शम्भुः पिनाकी शशिशेखरः .....

is said to be given by Vishnu to Parvati. Which Purana contains this 1) stotram 2) Dhyana sloka which starts os Dhavala Vapusham... and 3) what is story behind vishnu telling this to parvati?

Please mention the Khanda and Chapter of the Purana.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The śivāṣṭottara śatanāma stotram is from Śiva Rahasya Khaṇḍa of Śaṅkara Saṃhitā of Skanda Purāṇam. Nilakantha Diskshita wrote a commentary on śivāṣṭottara śatanāma stotram called [Śiva Tattva Rahasyam](https://archive.org/details/Sivatattvarahasya_Commentary_on_108_Names_of_Siva_by_Nilakantha_Dikshita_1915). In that he writes

> आद्या सनत्कुमारीया द्वितीया सूतसंहिता । ब्राह्मी तु संहिता
>   पश्चात्तुरीया वैष्णवी मता ॥
>
> पञ्चमी शाङ्करी ज्ञेया सौरी षष्ठी तु संहिता इति ।
>
> तत्र पञ्चम्यां शङ्करसंहितायां शिवरहस्यखण्डे गौरीनारायणसंवादे गौर्यै
>   विष्णुनोपदिष्टं शिवनामाष्टोत्तरशतं व्याख्यायते ॥
>
> In Skanda Purāṇa, first is Sanatkumāra Saṃhitā, second is Sūta Saṃhitā,
>   third is Brahma Saṃhitā, fourth is Vaishṇava Saṃhitā, fifth is Sankara
>   Saṃhitā and sixth Saura Saṃhitā. In that fifth Sankara Saṃhitā's Siva
>   Rahasya Khanda, I am commenting on the 108 names of Siva which were
>   given as a dialogue between Narayana and Parvati.

The stotra starts as

> पार्वत्युवाच -
>
> शरीरार्धमहं शंभोर्येन प्राप्स्यामि केशव । तदिदानीं ममाचक्ष्व स्तोत्रं
>   शीघ्रफलप्रदम् ॥
>
> Parvati said -
>
> O Narayana how do I obtain one half of Siva's body? Tell me that
>   stotra which gives me this result as quick as possible.
>
> नारायण उवाच -
>
> अस्ति गुह्यतमं गौरि नाम्नामष्टोत्तरं शतम् । शंभोरहं प्रवक्ष्यामि पठतां
>   शीघ्रकामदाम् ॥
>
> Narayana said -
>
> O Gauri, I will tell you the most secret  Ashtottara Nāmas of Shambhu
>   which gives quick results upon reciting.

The stotra is

> नारायण ऋषिः । अनुष्टुप्छन्दः । सदाशिवो देवता ।
>
> ध्यानम् -
>
> धवलवपुषमिन्दोर्मण्डले संनिविष्टं
>
> भुजगवलयहारं भस्मदिग्धङ्गमीशम् ।
>
> हरिणपरशुपाणिं चारुचन्द्रार्धमौलिं
>
> ह्रदयकमलमध्ये संततं चिन्तयामि ॥
>
> शिवो महेश्वरश्शम्भुः पिनाकी शशिशेखरः । वामदेवो विरूपाक्षः कपर्दी
>   नीललोहितः ॥ १॥
>
> शङ्करश्शूलपाणिश्च खट्वाङ्गी विष्णुवल्लभः । शिपिविष्टोऽम्बिकानाथः
>   श्रीकण्ठो भक्तवत्सलः ॥ २॥
>
> भवश्शर्वस्त्रिलोकेशश्शितिकण्ठश्शिवाप्रियः । उग्रः कपाली कामारिः
>   अन्धकासुरसूदनः ॥ ३॥
>
> गङ्गाधरो ललाटाक्षः कालकालः कृपानिधिः । भीमः परशुहस्तश्च
>   मृगपाणिर्जटाधरः ॥ ४॥
>
> कैलासवासी कवची कठोरस्त्रिपुरान्तकः । वृषाङ्को वृषभारूढो
>   भस्मोद्धूलितविग्रहः ॥ ५॥
>
> सामप्रियस्स्वरमयस्त्रयीमूर्तिरनीश्वरः । सर्वज्ञः परमात्मा च
>   सोमसूर्याग्निलोचनः ॥ ६॥
>
> हविर्यज्ञमयस्सोमः पञ्चवक्त्रस्सदाशिवः । विश्वेश्वरो वीरभद्रो गणनाथः
>   प्रजापतिः ॥ ७॥
>
> हिरण्यरेता दुर्धर्षः गिरीशो गिरिशोऽनघः । भुजङ्गभूषणो भर्गो गिरिधन्वा
>   गिरिप्रियः ॥ ८॥
>
> कृत्तिवासा पुरारातिर्भगवान् प्रमथाधिपः ।
>   मृत्युञ्जयस्सूक्ष्मतनुर्जगद्व्यापी जगद्गुरुः ॥ ९॥
>
> व्योमकेशो महासेनजनकश्चारुविक्रमः । रुद्रो भूतपतिः स्थाणुरहिर्भुध्न्यो
>   दिगम्बरः ॥ १०॥
>
> अष्टमूर्तिरनेकात्मा सात्त्विकश्शुद्धविग्रहः । शाश्वतः खण्डपरशुरजः
>   पाशविमोचकः ॥ ११॥
>
> मृडः पशुपतिर्देवो महादेवोऽव्ययो हरिः । पूषादन्तभिदव्यग्रो 
>   दक्षाध्वरहरो हरः ॥ १२॥
>
> भगनेत्रभिदव्यक्तो सहस्राक्षस्सहस्रपात् । अपवर्गप्रदोऽनन्तस्तारकः
>   परमेश्वरः ॥ १३॥
>
> एतदष्टोत्तरं नाम्नां शतमान्नायसंमितम् । शंकरस्य प्रिया गौरी जप्त्वा
>   शंभुप्रसाददम् ॥
>
> त्रैलोक्यमन्वहं देवी वर्षमेकं प्रयत्नतः । अवाप सा शरीरार्धं
>   प्रसादाच्छूलपाणिनः ॥
>
> यस्त्रिसंध्यं पठेन्नित्यं नाम्नामष्टोत्तरं शतम् ।
>   शतरुद्रत्रिरावृत्त्या यत्फलं लभते नरः ॥
>
> तत्फलं प्राप्नुयान्नित्यमेकावृत्त्या न संशयः । सकृद्वा नामभिः पूज्य
>   कुलकोटिं समुद्धरेत् ॥
>
> बिल्वपत्रैः प्रशस्तैश्च  पुष्पैश्च तुलसीदलैः । तिलाक्षतैर्यजेद्यस्तु
>   जीवन्मुक्तो न संशयः ॥

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice find. So u already knew this or only a recent find?

Comment: @Rickross recent find. I almost forgot about this question.

Comment: @Student please if you could post the link from where you got these stotram or else if you can translate the phala shruthi एतदष्टोत्तरं नाम्नां शतमान्नायसंमितम् । शंकरस्य प्रिया गौरी जप्त्वा शंभुप्रसाददम् ॥

त्रैलोक्यमन्वहं देवी वर्षमेकं प्रयत्नतः । अवाप सा शरीरार्धं प्रसादाच्छूलपाणिनः ॥

यस्त्रिसंध्यं पठेन्नित्यं नाम्नामष्टोत्तरं शतम् । शतरुद्रत्रिरावृत्त्या यत्फलं लभते नरः ॥

तत्फलं प्राप्नुयान्नित्यमेकावृत्त्या न संशयः । सकृद्वा नामभिः पूज्य कुलकोटिं समुद्धरेत् ॥

बिल्वपत्रैः प्रशस्तैश्च पुष्पैश्च तुलसीदलैः । तिलाक्षतैर्यजेद्यस्तु जीवन्मुक्तो न संशयः ॥

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao You can download the copy from https://archive.org/details/Sivatattvarahasya_Commentary_on_108_Names_of_Siva_by_Nilakantha_Dikshita_1915

Comment: Do we need any initiation for Shiva Asttotarasata shotram ? Or any rules are prescribed ?