# Is there an English translation of the book Shri Shiva Tattva Rahasya?

Tags: shiva, puranas, shiva-purana, shaivism, stotra

I wanted to learn more about **Shiva Ashtotthara Shatanama Stotram.**

So [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15417/which-purana-has-shiva-ashtottara-stotram) was an answer which showed me the source of the stotram. And this answer also referred to **[Shri Shiva Tattva Rahasya](https://archive.org/details/Sivatattvarahasya_Commentary_on_108_Names_of_Siva_by_Nilakantha_Dikshita_1915/page/n1)** written by **Nilakanta Dikshitar**, who, if I remember properly is nephew of the great **Appayya Dikshitar**.

So this would be a **very precious work** and the given link is that of a Sanskrit book. It would be beneficial for all if some one could post a link for English translated version of it if it exists.

If not so, if anyone has read this book and can take up the work of summarizing and telling the gist of it as much as they can would highly appreciated.

Comment: I think this the 2nd time u hv offered bounty on this Q. Am I right?

Comment: @Rickross yes, I wanted to know it. It's costed me 150 points, as you can see I am a poor man, this is the last attempt here on SE for this

Comment: Ok .. yes in this way u'll be a pauper. Better to wait patiently for an answer.

Comment: I can't take back the bounty

Comment: I am not sure abt how things work with bounty but probably u can't..

Comment: Once you offer bounty you cannot get it back in any way